# PageViews for Google Analytics Plugin for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I'm learning about [Google Analytics for Unity](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/reference) and also learning about Google Analytics in general.  For some games, it would be really useful to have page views:

Imagine your game has 20 levels.  You want to track what level people get to before they quit because that correlates to how engaged they were and how fun the game is.

[image]

As you can see above, the Audience Overview already has a Pages / Session metric.  If you could define each level in a game as a page, then the Pages / Session would give you a lot of useful information.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to set pages in the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/reference).  Does anyone know how I could do this?  Is it really easy to make something equivalent with a custom metric/dimension?

To summarize, there are two different answers that would help me and I'd accept either:

1. A way to use this plugin to define page views
2. A way to use this plugin to give me something equivalent to Pages / Session (i.e., Levels / Session).  But, I'd like an answer for this to include how to *view* the Levels / Session, not just collect the data.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.  The mistake I made is creating a GA view of type "Website."  I should have created one of type "App."  The difference is explained here:  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553#WebVersusAppViews

The plugin has the ability to send ScreenName's which are effectively PageViews.  But, unless my view is setup as App, GA won't really give any reports that show the ScreenNames.

So, it was a matter of creating a new view, then sending ScreenNames as described here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/reference#screen-basic